# Drawer indicator (hamburger) scrambled on Android 4.1, 4.2,4.3

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

On pre lollipop devices, the material drawer animation gets stuck in the middle while the drawer is closing.

- To reproduce -

  1 . i do a fragment transaction (add/replace).

  2 . Change the drawer indicator to "back"/"up" button. Press on it, go back. Back button animates to hamburger as it should.

  3 . Now if i open the drawer by swiping left to right, close it - It animates back to the hamburger image just fine. But if i open the drawer by pressing the hamburger button and THEN come back, the animation (back button to hamburger) begins but gets stuck in the middle. You could repeat Step 3 as many times as you like and you will get the same scrambled result.

[[image: The scrambled drawer state[1]]

- It happens consistently.
- This happens only on (AFAIK) devices running
  Android 4.1,4.2,4.3
- I've also tested it on 5.0 , 5.1 and it works as
  expected there.

I am using the support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

Comment: 23.0.1 is the last version for the appcompat-v7, did you try using it ?

Comment: Yes.. I tried older and newer versions just for this thing. Same result.